# Typescript: Changing the definition of some third party types d.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am a little bit lost how to do the following.

I am trying to change the definitions of some third party types by creating a new file `thirdParty.d.ts`.

Let's suppose the third party returns Class A

```
class A {
    // ...
}
```

In my `third-party.d.ts` file, I want to introduce two new parameters.

```
import * as thirdParty from 'thirdParty'
decalre module 'thirdParty' {
    export interface A extends thirdParty.A {
        newParam1: number
        newParam2: number
    }
}
```

Then, let's overwrite class A by adding `newParam1` and `newParam2`

```
class ExtendedA extends A {
    newParam1 = 1
    newParam2 = 2
}
```

So now everything looks good. Every instance of class A recognizes the new parameters. In any function or class it's possible to call newParam1 without casting.

```
randomMethod() {
 console.log(this.a.newParam1) // Returns 1. No need to cast (this.a as ExtendedA).newParam1 !
}
```

However, since I changed the definition of class A. And ExtendedA extends it. Deleting the new parameters will not generate errors. Which worries me. I am looking for a way to force `ExtendedA` to decalre the new parameters.

```
// This is bad :(    
class ExtendedA extends A { // implements Interface will not work either
    // newParam1 = 1 // Commented but there is no errors ! Which is bad
    // newParam2 = 2
}
```

I am sure the fix is pretty easy but I am really lost

Comment: Your interface did declare that every `A` *has* these properties (from whatever source). Not that it needs them. Where does  `this.a` get the new properties from if it's not an `ExtendedA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to merge a class definition. This is at the moment disallowed. check here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#disallowed-merges

As pointed out in the docs... you can extend the third party class with mixins. But you would be essentially generating a new class:
From the docs:

```
// To get started, we need a type which we'll use to extend
// other classes from. The main responsibility is to declare
// that the type being passed in is a class.
 
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};
 
// This mixin adds a scale property, with getters and setters
// for changing it with an encapsulated private property:
 
function Scale<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Scaling extends Base {
    // Mixins may not declare private/protected properties
    // however, you can use ES2020 private fields
    _scale = 1;
 
    setScale(scale: number) {
      this._scale = scale;
    }
 
    get scale(): number {
      return this._scale;
    }
  };
}
```

What will work as you epect is if you try to create a new Class that implements the original, like so:

```
//========= ./third-party/third-party =========
export class A {
  foo = 'foo';
}

//========= index.ts =========
import {A} from './third-party/third-party';

declare module './third-party/third-party' {
    interface A {
        newParam1: string;
        newParam2: number
    }
}
// ideally you should extend the functionality also:
// those are type safe;
// A.prototype.newParam1 = 'something';
// A.prototype.newParam2 = 20;

class B implements A {
  foo='else';
  newParam1='';
  newParam2=20;
}

const b = new B();
console.log(b.newParam1)
```

But for that you would need to implement all Class A functionalities or come up with a delegation pattern or something.

Here's a simple repl to use as playground: https://replit.com/@tiagobnobrega/module-extension#index.ts

Comment: The problem with that that I have to write the third party class from scratch, which is something I can't do. I am looking at least to force class B, somehow, to `overwite` only newParam1 and newParam2.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to create a new class and extend it using mixing as the first example. It would be using a new class for the new functionalities. But you would be able to use the new class on functions that expects the original one or returns the original one. But for functions using new functionalities, should expect the new class. Or just use the "as newClass", but that opts out of type safety